# Google Maps: Dynamically Movable and Resizable Circle Overlay Script for v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Ok, I just found the perfect script I was looking for.

http://web3o.blogspot.com.br/2010/05/google-maps-dynamically-movable-and.html

You can add circles with lat/long and radius on Google Maps.
The problem is that this script it's **only for v2 api.**

I found this one too
http://www.mapdevelopers.com/draw-circle-tool.php

But there's no code or source available on it :(

Does anybody know any script like these that could work on v3?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That functionality is built in to the [Google Maps API v3 Drawing Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools)

[Example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/drawing-tools)

You can customize it to just allow circles (or just allow one circle).

[Working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_drawing-tools_Circle.html)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
    drawingControl: false,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE
      ]
    },
    circleOptions: {
      fillColor: '#ffff00',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 5,
      clickable: false,
      editable: true,
      zIndex: 1
    }
  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
    // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
  });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map-canvas,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
}
@media print {
  html,
  body {
    height: auto;
  }
  #map-canvas,
  #map_canvas {
    height: 650px;
  }
}
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -180px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
    drawingControl: false,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE
      ]
    },
    circleOptions: {
      fillColor: '#ffff00',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 5,
      clickable: false,
      editable: true,
      zIndex: 1
    }
  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
    // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
  });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map-canvas,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
}
@media print {
  html,
  body {
    height: auto;
  }
  #map-canvas,
  #map_canvas {
    height: 650px;
  }
}
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -180px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```